# Несколько подписей для git коммита

Tags: git, github, git-commit, gpg

В гите есть возможность указать любого автора коммита. Тогда на гитхабе будет показано, что ты закоммитил (*commiter*), а другой человек был автором (*authored by*). Также можно добавить в коммит строку `Co-authored-by: AUTHOR <MAIL>` с указанием дополнительных авторов. Тогда на гитхабе будет указано несколько авторов.

Проблема в том, что в таком случае коммиты будут считаться на гитхабе *Partially verified* (если включён *Vigilant mode*), т.к. только *commiter* сделал GPG-подпись, а не все указанные авторы. Можно ли как-то добавить несколько подписей одному коммиту, чтобы подобные коммиты гитхаб показывал как *Verified*?